# what is the no. of possible parellelograms?

Tags: geometry

A parallelogram having an acute angle of 30 degrees whose area is equal to the perimeter and the sides are whole numbers then number of such parallelograms possible are?

Comment: give names to the elements of your parallelogram. How the height relates to the oblique side? How you computer the area? How you compute perimeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We interpret the question to mean that we want to find the number of (unordered) pairs $a$, $b$ of integers that can be the sides. The perimeter is $2a+2b$. The area is twice the area of the triangle we get by joining the two vertices at which there is a $150^\circ$ angle.

The area of each of these triangles is $(1/2)(ab)(\sin 30^\circ)$, for a total of $(1/2)ab$. So we are looking at the equation $2a+2b=(1/2)(ab)$, or equivalently $ab=4a+4b$.

This equation can be rewritten as $(a-4)(b-4)=16$.  Thus $a-4$ and $b-4$ must have product $16$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $a\le b$.

It is easy to see that $a-4$ and $b-4$ cannot both be negative. So $a-4=1$, $b-4=16$, or $a-4=2$, $b-4=8$, or $a-4=4$, $b-4=4$.

That gives three parallelograms: one with sides $5$ and $20$; another with sides $6$ and $12$;  and finally the rhombus with sides $8$ and $8$.

Comment: Well, there is the degenerate case of $a=b=0$, whether or not  that counts is entirely up to the person who wrote the problem in the first place.

Comment: True, perhaps the OP can assess how degenerate the problem setter may be, and whether "whole number" includes $0$, which is more like a hole number.

Comment: Thanks Andre,I was able to reach upto ab=4a+4b, just couldn't find the number of unordered pairs.
Please ignore the case,where a=b=0. if both the sides are zero then there wont be any angle of 30 degree between them.

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the "trick" used is a relative of completing the square.